# Identify-this-object tag potentially misapplied? Should it be slightly broadened in scope?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

It was called to my attention in since-deleted comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36548/12102) that I might have mis-applied the [identify-this-object](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-object) tag a few times.

Current definition:

> Questions which ask for an object in a photograph or other media to be identified and/or have its function described.

Questionable usage:

- [What were the “pills” that were added to solid waste in Apollo 7?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36203/12102) object portrayed in *audio media*

Probably incorrect usage:

- [Where is Farside's 4th stage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36260/12102)
- [Have there been any Foucault pendulum demonstrations in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36020/12102)

So I'd like to ask...

1. Does the tag belong on these questions as currently defined?
2. Is it a good idea to broaden the definition to include "name that tune" or "what card am I thinking of" type questions, or *should we leave the definition of the tag alone, considering it's been working fairly nicely as-is?*

**note:** We already have the [record](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record) tag for questions of the class "What's the X-est Y...", so there's that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO - the "questionable" one is fine, but the other two should be untagged. I don't think a general "identify-this" tag is useful. That's kind of the point of most questions: to explain the phenomenon the person asked about.

Answer (score 0):

## Change [identifty-this-object](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identifty-this-object) to [indentify-this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentify-this) (or just change the description)!

**We can just remove object and change the description from:**

Questions which ask for an object in a photograph or other media to be identified and/or have its function described.

**To something like:**

Questions which ask for something to be identified given a specific set of information/details, picture, or other media and have its function described.

**Feel free to edit the descriptions, I am horribly bad at descriptive writing.**